# Why Яковлев/Яковлевич with the intrusive -л-?

Tags: этимология, выбор-имени

As the title says, why are the surname and patronymic formed from Яков Яковлев and Яковлевич instead of *Яковов and *Яковович? Where did this **-л-** come from? Is it simply because Яковлев(ич) is more euphonious than *Яковов(ич)? If so, аre there other examples where words or names formed from a root add an **-л-** through the same process by which it was added to Яков?

Also, am I correct in thinking -л- was chosen for the same reasons -л- shows up in certain first-person verb conjugations, i.e. оставить --> остав**л**ю?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Phonetic hypothesis seems valid; cf. surnames Ивлев, Кузовлев.

Comment: nice, never though about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surnames and patronimic names were formed with suffixes. The mystery of the surnames Ивлев(Иевлев) and Яковлев is explained in the book by **Убенгаун Б.О. Русские фамилии**. They were  not formed directly from Christian names (Яков, Иов), but from the adjective with the suffix -л(ь)- meaning "belonging to "(Яковль, Иевль). We can still see this suffix in the names of old Russian cities (Ярославль-belonging to Ярослав (the king). They say the usage of two patronimic suffixes helped to avoid pronunciation difficulties.(-овов).

> Яков--Яковль--Яковлев--Яковлевич.

Comment: the name of the town of `Путивль` must be of the same patterm

Comment: Sure, Переяславль, Путивль, perhaps some more.

Comment: Ярославль is not 'belonging to' but rather the name itself, eh?

Comment: @bipll: no it's not. The person's name is *Ярослав* and *Ярославль* is something that belongs to him.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, am I correct in thinking -л- was chosen for the same reasons -л- shows up in certain first-person verb conjugations, i.e. оставить --> оставлю?

Exactly, this is so called "epenthetic l". It was inserted in Proto-Slavic between a labial consonant and *j*, and is common for East Slavic languages in all positions, and all Slavic languages in the first syllable.

That's why we have word pairs like *земля / земной*, *рубль / рубить*, *травля / травить* etc.

> If so, аre there other examples where words or names formed from a root add an -л- through the same process by which it was added to Яков

Any root ending in a labial (*б*, *п*, *в*, *ф*, *м*) would add it if the paradigm requires putting a *j* after it.

The paradigm which gave *Яковлевич* is not productive anymore, however you can see it fossilized in the names like *Ярославль, Переяслявль, Лихославль* etc.

If we take any productive paradigm, say, the one you mentioned, we can see it applies even to the words borrowed long after the Proto-Slavic split: *графить / графлю / графлёный* etc.

Comment: "Exactly, this is so called 'epenthetic l'. It was inserted in Proto-Slavic between a labial consonant and j, and is common for East Slavic languages in all positions [...]" Thanks for the answer. I'm a little unclear still, however, on why there was a "soft" consonant (е) after Яков to begin with, thus requiring the epenthetic l. Isn't it customary to append -**о**вич to non-palatalized consonants? Since **о** is a hard vowel (no preceding _/j/_), wouldn't that render the epenthetic l unnecessary? Basically my question is why was -евич being added to Яков and not -ович?

Comment: @Гамлет: that's a contamination of two possessive endings: older in *-ь* and newer in *-ев/-ов*. See the names listed in the Primary Chronicle: *Вуефастъ Святославль, Улѣбъ Володиславль, Шибьридъ Алдань* would have been *Святославов, Володиславов* and *Алданов* nowadays. *Яковлев* is a mix of the two paradigms. It's not productive anymore: Magnus Nyren's Russian patronymic was _Олафович_, not _*Олафлевич_